# How can I implement google hreflang in Angular8 dynamically?

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement google hreflang inside of index.html in Angular

```
// index.html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Commontown</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="google-site-verification" content="jb7HCud2Xsfwwefwef3GEGDSVVDEERDE" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/type.css">
  <link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://www.example.co/en">
  <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script>
    const path = window.location.path // /en
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Suppose I want to insert

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://www.example.co/en/blog">
```

this line. But I do not want to hard code it between head tag.

I want javascript reads url path 'blog' and replace "href=https://www.example.co/en" to "href=https://www.example.co/en/blog" dynamically.

However, **window.location.href** inside script tag works only once when a website initially rendered therefore I am getting only '/en'.

Is it possible to implement hreflang tag inside of angular template other than index.html?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try that to dynamically add a link

```
import {DOCUMENT} from "@angular/common";
import {Renderer2} from '@angular/core';


constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any, private renderer: Renderer2)
{
}

constructor()
{

    const linkElt = this.renderer.createElement('link');
    this.renderer.setAttribute(linkElt, 'rel', 'alternate');
    this.renderer.setAttribute(linkElt, 'hreflang', 'en');
    this.renderer.setAttribute(linkElt, 'href', https://www.example.co/en/blog");
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.document.head, linkElt);
}
```

If you want to modify an existing link value, you need to identify the link first

```
let arr = Array.from(this.document.head.children);
let linkElt = arr.find(e => e.rel == "alternate" && e.hreflang =="en");
this.renderer.setAttribute(linkElt, 'href', https://www.example.co/en/blog");
```

Comment: Thanks it helps me a lot but one quick question... I check that hreflang link tag created inside of head tag but it is located middle of many style tags. is this could be a problem in respect of SEO? (btw, I wrote the code inside of app.component.html file)

Comment: It does not matter where it is I think

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't matter?