# How to add hreflang tags in SAP Spartacus

Tags: spartacus-storefront

We have *multiple basestores* with *multiple languages* and want to *implement the hreflang tags to all pages* (if easier, it might not include cart and checkout) telling the searchengines that there are multiple versions of the same page in different languages.

We followed the guide on [Automatic Context Configuration](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/automatic-context-configuration/) to provide the multiple basestores.
We also added the `SiteContextSelectorComponent` to allow the user to change the language.
At the moment all pages face the same structure:
`https://company.com/us/en/c/CategoryName` -> where **`us`** is the **country** and **`en`** the **language**

Other examples:
`https://company.com/us/es/c/CategoryName` -> `us` store with spanish language
`https://company.com/us/de/c/CategoryName` -> `us` store with german language
`https://company.com/de/de/c/CategoryName` -> `de` german store with german language

The hreflang tags should be generated like

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-us" href="https://company.com/us/en/c/CategoryName" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es-us" href="https://company.com/us/es/c/CategoryName" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de-us" href="https://company.com/us/de/c/CategoryName" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de-de" href="https://company.com/de/en/c/CategoryName" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://company.com/c/CategoryName" />
```

Working with meta resolvers might not work, due to the fact, that the tags are `link` and not `meta`.

So what's the spartcus way to do this?

A (angular) solution might be, injecting the document and adding the tags this [way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61360026/2681480). But is this really the preferred way?
And a further question would be, where's the right place to add these tags (on languageswitch? or routechange?)

Kind regards and thanks for your help,
Andreas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment of writing, Spartacus doesn't have a mechanism for declaring in the `<head>` of the document the language-oriented alternate URLs.

However, Spartacus already implements the mechanism for resolving the [canonical URL](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/html-tags/#canonical-urls). It's based on the concept of multiple `PageMetaResolver`s and the core `PageMetaService`. Then the `SeoMetaService` observes the resolved meta-data for the current page and updates the document with appropriate canonical URL link, title, and other data.

You will need to write a customization for "alternate" links. And here are my recommendations how to do it:

- extend the `SeoMetaService` and perhaps `PageMetaLinkService` - for phisically placing the links in the head of the document
- perhaps extend the `PageMetaConfig` and `PageMetaService` for resolving specific values for your alternate links

The concrete strategy of resolving the "alternate" links might vary from customer to customer. Your case seems to be simple, since you don't have any localisation of the URL segments (e.g. `/category/xxx` in English vs. `/categoría/xxx` in Spanish). Your URLs seem to only vary in the URL prefix - the standard URL site context. Then you can derive your specific "alternate" links from the *canonical URL* (which Spartacus already have implemented) and replace only the language in the prefix of the URL path, e.g. using a `RegExp`.

Since you don't need a different strategy of resolving "alternate" links for different pages (e.g. different strategy for PDP and different for PLP), then you might "hardcode" your way of resolving "alternate" links either in your customized `PageMetaService` or `SeoMetaService`. In other words, you won't need to bother with customizing each and every existing `PageMetaResolver`.